# How does Google billing work when exceeding API loads?

Tags: google, api

I would like to have information about the Google API that we use to integrate Google Maps and Google reviews on our website pages.

My question is: Google indicates that a billing will be done if we exceed $200 (more than 25,800 API loads), I would like to know if I will be billed only on the difference above $200 or if I will be billed the $200 + the extra cost of API loads?

I tried to find detailled answers on Google but I didn't..